# Is it possible to put a constructor function inside a constructor function inside another constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am making a project where Python 3 features can be added into JavaScript. For example, "in".
My question is, can I make a constructor function inside a constructor function inside a constructor? For example:

```
var foo = new function foo() {
    this.bar = function(Variable1) {
        this.def = function() {
            // code
        }
        return ""; // to prevent error with undefined
    }
```

foo and foo.bar(var1) works, but foo.bar(var1).def doesn't. I messed with it and tried to do foo.def, and it worked. I'm confused; why does `foo.def` work, but not `foo.bar(var1).def`?
[Why am I thinking of doing this? I want to replicate the "in" keyword from Python 3 (like 
`if (5 in [5, 2, 3]): ... # returns true`) to make it easier (`for (var i = 0; etc.)`) to do in JavaScript. In that case, I wanted to do something like `foo.v("h").$in.v2("hello world")` returns true. Thanks for all the help!]
**EDIT:** Thanks for all the help from all the commenters. ;)

Comment: *contructor-inception*... sorry, I had to say it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. `[5,2,3].indexOf(5)` and `"hello world".indexOf("h")` works just fine. You can make it so `foo.bar(var1).def` works; there are several ways to do it but without an idea of what you want out of it, it's hard to say how to do it.

Comment: @Halcyon, I want something that will make it seem more like Python, like "in". I'm trying to find a way to make a constructor function inside another constructor function inside a constructor, meaning like `document.getElementById("").innerHTML.` document is the main constructor, getElementById("") is the constructor function and innerHTML is the constructor function of getElementById.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is fluent API. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: Those aren't constructors, they're just objects. `document` is an object, it has a property `getElementById` that's a function that returns another object.

Comment: Constructor functions have to be called with `new`. You are not calling `bar` with `new`. However, I'd recommend to take a step, research more about constructor functions and think about whether you really need/want them.

Comment: @Halcyon thanks for the help! :) If you want, you can make that an answer.

Comment: @Christian You are abusing the term "constructor". Not all functions that return objects are constructors (in fact, most of them are not). You need need to (and should not) have a constructor *function* inside the other function, you only need to *construct* (create an object, or call a function that does) there.

Comment: But yeah, I guess I should research more about constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to do something like `foo.v("h").$in.v2("hello world")` returns [sic] true

Since you don't want to call `foo` as a constructor (there's no `new` in your example), you don't want `foo` to be a constructor. Just have it return an object with a `v` property which refers to a function that, in turn, stores the value given to it and returns an object with an `$in` property (and probably others) which returns a function (functions) with a `v2` property that calculates the result.

For example, here those are all the same object, but you may well use different objects for different states; see comments:

```js
// The operations we allow, including how many operands they expect
var operations = {
    // We'll just do $in for now
    $in: {
        operandCount: 2,
        exec: function(operands) {
            return String(operands[1]).indexOf(String(operands[0])) != -1;
        }
    }
};
// Prototype of objects returned by `foo`
var proto = {
    // `v` sets the next operand; if we have an operation and we have enough
    // operands, it executes the operation; if not, returns `this` for chaining
    v(operand) {
        if (!this.operands) {
            this.operands = [];
        }
        this.operands.push(operand);
        if (this.operation && this.operation.operandCount == this.operands.length) {
            return this.operation.exec(this.operands);
        }
        return this;
    },
    // `$in` is defined as a property with a getter to satisfy your syntax.
    // In general, getters with side-effects (like this one) are a Bad Thing™,
    // but there can be exceptions... Returns `this` because `$in` is an infix
    // operator.
    get $in() {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty("operation")) {
            throw new Error("Cannot specify multiple operations");
        }
        this.operation = operations.$in;
        return this;
    }
};

// `foo` just creates the relevant object
function foo() {
    return Object.create(proto);
}

// Examples:
console.log("Should be true:", foo().v("h").$in.v("hello world"));
console.log("Should be false:", foo().v("h").$in.v("nope, don't 'ave it"));
```

Answer (score -2):

`foo.bar(var1)` is called,the result should be the return value of function bar.Function bar have no return value,so `foo.bar(var1).def` doesn't work.

Comment: I've added a return value, but I forgot to add that into the sample code. It doesn't work.

Comment: what is the return value that you add?Does it have `def` property?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question